# How do I use polymorphism with Spring Beans?

Tags: spring, polymorphism, javabeans

Here is the premise for what I'm doing:
- Use a simple servlet to get page requests.
- Get a page id from the request to determine which page i'm on.
- Define the controllers in a beans xml config.
- Use the bean definition to determine which page controller class to use.
- All of these page controllers extends CORE.Controllers.PageController class.

Here is what I am trying to do, but failing. I'm trying to load the page controller class (PersonController, which was determined from the beans) into the PageController variable. What you will see in my code sample is that I'm casting it into the PageController class. That doesn't work.

**How do I get my PersonController object from the bean factory using polymorphism, into my variable?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- -->
<bean id="home" name="home" class="CORE.Controllers.HomeController" />
<bean id="person" name="person" class="CORE.Controllers.PersonController" />

<!-- Property Management -->
<bean id="propertyEvaluator" class="CORE.Controllers.PropertyManagement.PropertyEvaluator" />
</beans>
```

The class is here in part:

```
String pageId = "home";
    if (request.getParameter("PID") != null)
    {
        pageId = request.getParameter("PID");
    }

    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8"); // Set content type for HTML.
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); // Output goes to the response PrintWriter.
    try
    {
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        String ctx = getServletContext().getRealPath("") + FS; //get the real path for xml and xsl files.

        BeanFactory pageFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource(ctx+"WEB-INF/page-cfg.xml"));
        PageMapping pageMap = (PageMapping) pageFactory.getBean("pageMapping");
        Page page = pageMap.getPageById(pageId);

        BeanFactory controllerFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource(ctx+"WEB-INF/controller-cfg.xml"));
        PageController controller = (PageController) controllerFactory.getBean(page.getControllerName());
        controller.setRequest(request);
```

Comment: If you're not getting a `PersonController`, what is the type of the bean you're getting back?

Comment: PageController is what I get back, because I'm casting it into that. I could cast it into PersonController, but I lose the configurability from Spring Beans. So the casting is not going to work. I need a different solution.

Comment: So your PageController variable references a PersonController object - that's polymorphism! Can you explain more what you want, since I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: The following is what I originally tried, but it doesn't compile: 
  
PageController controller = controllerFactory.getBean(page.getControllerName()); // the object would be PersonController, but this class only recognizes controllerFactory.getBean(page.getControllerName()) as a generic Object, thus not compiling.

I need to think this through to try to find a better way to ask the question.

Comment: out of curiousity: why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I wish I had a white-board to explain. I'll just run up the layers. I'm using mySql to keep the data. Hybernate to do the queries. Java Controllers to instantiate the data and marshal the data into xml. This xml gets distributed through web services or web servlets. I'm using the Spring beans to manage which controller is used for the web servlet. I want a single servlet that arbitrates the requests. That's where I'm running into the above issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the update. I think I understand now - you want to avoid the cast to `PageController`.

Replace

```
PageController controller = (PageController)controllerFactory
    .getBean(page.getControllerName());
```

with

```
PageController controller = controllerFactory
    .getBean(page.getControllerName(), PageController.class);
```

Spring allows you to parameterize the `getBean` call with the type of the expected bean. In terms of implmentation "under the hood" it's still a cast, and you'll get a `ClassCastException` if the named bean doesn't correspond to the requested type, but at least now the compiler is handling this via generics.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring, if we use JDK proxy (as @mdma corrected below), we can't cast an object to a concrete class instance, we're only able to cast it to in interface instance. In this case, you need to change PageController to an interface and have an implementation for it, named PageControllerImpl and declare it in you controller-cfg.xml.

If CGLIB is used, your code might ok.

Comment: While that's true if you are using AOP (and JDK proxies) it's not generally true. A context can instantiate exactly the classes you specify and provide them "as is".